# How do I get a grunt task working with a Cloudbees Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, gruntjs

I'm trying to get a Jenkins build up and running on Cloudbees. I've successfully gotten NodeJs installed and my source pulled from my BitBucket repository. I am trying to run my grunt task to minify and concatenate my JS and CSS files before deploying. However, I am not able to run the grunt program, even though it is successfully installed. Below is my build script:

```
curl -s -o use-node https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/node/use-node
NODE_VERSION=0.8.0 \
 source ./use-node
npm install
npm install grunt
grunt
```

I've tried installing grunt with and without the -g option without success. Here is the console output for the grunt portion of my build:

```
+ npm install grunt
...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
...
grunt@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.11
├── which@1.0.5
├── iconv-lite@0.2.7
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
├── rimraf@2.0.3 (graceful-fs@1.1.14)
├── minimatch@0.2.11 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.2.2)
├── glob@3.1.21 (graceful-fs@1.2.0, inherits@1.0.0)
├── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1)
└── js-yaml@1.0.3 (argparse@0.1.12)
+ grunt
/tmp/hudson3382014549646667419.sh: line 8: grunt: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? Is this even possible in Cloudbees?

Comment: I think nom install -g grunt may work - but let me reproduce and confirm below....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grunt is now broken up, annoyingly, into a separate cli module. Also, annoyingly, that cli module does not include grunt itself.

To make this work:

```
curl -s -o use-node https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/node/use-node
NODE_VERSION=0.8.0 \
 source ./use-node
npm install
npm install grunt
npm install grunt-cli
export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/
grunt
```

If the folk making this change how it works to be sensible, then it may change in future.

Docs here: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: Thank you, this got me past this hurdle. Kind of embarrassing that the answer was on the getting started page of GruntJs.

Comment: It is a good Q - glad to have it here as I will no doubt forget ! I meant to look at grunt. Also - this was a recent change. Until recently what you had would almost work, but since grunt 4 - no such luck. Good luck !

Comment: Would love to hear of your progress with grunt.js - I am thinking of switching some clickstarts to use it instead of bash for some tasks.

Comment: I've loved grunt so far. I haven't done anything very complex yet, but what I've used it for is working well. I've mostly just used it for minification and concatenation for production.

Comment: I like the approach to separate the grunt-cli from the grunt version you're using in your project. It lets you have multiple version of grunt on a single machine. Would be great to have *js ready* slaves (node.js, phantomjs, npm, and some packages installed globally such as grunt-cli, bower, testacular, etc.)

Comment: good idea ... I will look into it. Generally we don't want to put everything everywhere all the time, but having some js flavour makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup everything from a jenkins job, no ssh/command line required:

### Install Jenkins Plugins

- Git Plugin - *for git*
- Git Client Plugin - *for git*
- Git Parameter Plugin - *for git tags*
- GitHub API Plugin - *for github*
- NodeJS Plugin - *integration for common javascript tools NodeJS & npm*

### Git / Ant / Maven / NodeJS Installations

- Goto SERVER/jenkins/configure

Git

- Git -> Git installations -> Add Git -> JGit
- Git plugin -> Global Config user.name Value = "Anthony Mckale", Global Config user.email Value = "anthony.mckale@bskyb.com"

NodeJS

- NodeJS- > NodeJS installations -> Add NodeJS -> Name = "NodeJS 0.11.10", tick "Install automatically", select "Install from nodejs.org", add "grunt-cli" to globally installed packages

### TADA

and hopefully git/nodejs and grunt will be available to you

see the plugin wiki for more details how to add the grunt/node tasks to the jenkins job -> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

it's really easy :)

no ssh loggin required just jenkins admin rights